# MySql autocomplete query - for more then one word

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i'd like to know if there is a way to match more then one word when i type only one.
Let me explain. So here is the query i've just typed:

```
SELECT* 
FROM 
    rc_orders o
WHERE
    o.custCity 
LIKE 
    'sof%'
```

So that will select all the cities from the table starting with "sof". For example "Sofia". Or if i type "New" it will match the cities starting "new" -> "new york", "new jersey" etc.
But let me explain see what i am talking about. If i type "york", i want the autocomplete to display "new york". Or if i type "jersey", i'd like the query to match "new jersey" and so on.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

you could try with `regexp` in the where clause like

```
select * from `rc_orders` o where o.`custcity` regexp 'york';
```

Comment: Okay. My apologise but i still don't get the code above. Can you explain what the logic is?

Comment: @DesireOn, if you look at the link I provided in my answer you will see what regexp does.  There are a lot of resources on regular expressions, which is what this is doing.  It's a way to match strings using a defined set of rules.  For this case, you don't need to add in any complex special characters to get the regular expression to work.  Again, the link I provided in my answer also talks about regexp and where you would use it.  Both my answer and RamRaider's answer should work for what you are trying to achieve.  Have you tried either of them?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  If you add a `%` to the beginning of your string it will work as a pre-wildcard, returning results that match all, not just beginning with.

```
SELECT * FROM rc_orders o WHERE o.custCity LIKE '%sof%'
```

This link contains more information on pattern matching, including other options (like `regexp` as mentioned in another answer) for you to use as well.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: Explain what you did differently and why it should work.

Comment: I changed my comment after I spotted it. That is why you should tell them.

Comment: I will do just that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is doing  a search of custCity fields containing the second word (ex. jersey), which will return the whole city. this is the solution returning the 1st one.

```
SELECT TOP 1 o.cusstCity FROM rc_orders o WHERE o.custCity LIKE '%jersey%'
```

should return new jersey

I assuming there aren't two cities with the same second word, if not you'd need to do a Distinct search.

Comment: Unfortunately this query would fail, and I don't believe it would return "new jersey" since you don't have the wildcard at the beginning of 'jersey', but I may be wrong if TOP works differently in this situation.  I'm not sure why it would.  You're also missing the second ' after the %, which will cause this to fail.

Comment: Sorry I'm typing in the phone. Let me know if it works. I fixed the typos

Comment: That looks like it could work for the OP. But, it's the exact same solution as my answer now.

Comment: So you agree with the TOP 1 part. Thanks

Comment: I forgot about that part of it. I do not agree with it. She/he is wanting more than just one row returned based on the question. So, the difference between your answer and mine is that yours will only return one result, which it seems is not what she/he is looking for. I agree that it isn't clear that all results returned is wanted, and not just the top result, but I would be surprised if she/he would only want North Dakota being returned if someone typed in "Dakota". I would assume she/he would want both North Dakota and South Dakota to be returned.

Comment: I agree, but in your case if North Dakota is several times in the database the result will return repeated answers, but yes, we would need more information for giving a better answer.

Comment: Well, we would have to discuss why the database isn't normalized at that point then. It would contain duplicate values. But we could do distinct on that case as well. So top 1 wouldn't be the best approach for duplicate values either.

Comment: This looks like it is a good source for database normalization. https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php